# How to create a dynamic drop down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my HTML code.

```
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
<dt><a href="#"></a></dt>
<dd>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Advisory</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">People</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Universities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HR Intellegence</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Companies</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Notifications</a></li>
    </ul>
</dd>
```

And this is js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass("flagvisibility");

 $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
   $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
 });

 $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
   var text = $(this).html();
   $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
   $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
 });

 function getSelectedValue(id) {
   return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
 }

 $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
    var $clicked = $(e.target);
    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
  });

  $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
     $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
  });
});
```

This is a code for a drop down list that populates on click. I want to repeat it 100 times on my webpage and I don't want to copy the code and change the Class Name or ID for each entry. I remember there is some '.this' type function to do this but I don't know how to use it. Also I have some dynamic posts which contain this list so its JS can't be repeated on every single new entry.

Please suggest such changes in this code which will allow me to use '.dropdown' class with every entry without repeating the JS code and it opens only that drop down which is clicked to open.

Comment: Is Javascript _really_ needed or would you also accept a CSS-only solution?

Comment: yeah sure but the drop down should open on click only.

Comment: Oh okay. You could use [this small library](http://dev7studios.com/dropit/) for this. Very basic and shout fit your needs. Not much code but provide nearly the same structure and the open-on-click-only function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    html {
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .dropdown {
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .dropdown dd {
        display: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 0px #555;
        width: 180px;
        position: absolute;
        margin-left: 1px;
        margin-top: 1px;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }
    .dropdown ul {
        list-style: none;
        padding-left: 0px;
    }
    dt a {
        display: inline-block;
        background-color: #1b8be0;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .dropdown li a{
        text-decoration: none;
        color: #333;
    }
    .dropdown li {
        padding: 6px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .dropdown li:hover{
        background-color: #EEE;
        padding: 6px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<dl id="sample" class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#">Menu</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
<dl id="sample-2" class="dropdown">
    <dt><a href="#">Menu 2</a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">More News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">More Community</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(".dropdown dt a").click(function(e){
    $(this).parent().next().fadeToggle("fast");
});
$(".dropdown dt a").blur(function(e){
    if ($(e.target).not(".dropdown ul")){
        $(".dropdown dd").fadeOut();
    }
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: brother I got a problem.. I have some posts which are created on a button click. and these posts contain that list you provided. The problem is that when I create a new post then your dropdown don't works. i.e they are not working dynamically

Comment: just rebind all the js code when new post is created

Comment: what do you mean by rebind?

Comment: function rebindEvents(){

Comment: execute the dropdown js again when a new post is created

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79896/discussion-between-mian-kamran-and-uz4ir).

Answer (score 0):

Its better for you to use a front-end framework like Twitter Bootstrap or Zurb Foundation.

Comment: Brother, I want you to provide me options within the code I have provided.